# Laravel accessing array data

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

In laravel I'm currently dumping an array from my controller `dd($totals)` and it correctly dumps on the page in this format:

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "CURRENT" => "117"
    "PRIOR" => "90"
    "FULL" => "95"
  ]
]
```

However, when I access them in my table data rows it shows nothing in the table, making me think I'm not accessing it correctly maybe?

```
<td>{{ $totals->CURRENT}}</td>
<td>{{ $totals->PRIOR}}</td>
<td>{{ $totals->FULL}}</td>
```

This was previously working but I've changed the query which has slightly altered the array so maybe I need to access the data differently. How should I alter this so that laravel can properly display the array data.

Comment: That's a multidimensional array and that's also not how you access arrays in php...

Comment: That's how I access them in Laravel though. All of my other data is accessed this way but the arrays are structured differently

Comment: Surely Laravel should be throwing errors.

Comment: @Script47 I'm not getting any errors, it loads it's just empty

Comment: @TomN. that makes me think you really don't know what you're writing.  That's how you access objects, but there's nothing Laravel specific about how you access objects or arrays.  You should study up on data types a little bit more.

Comment: @TomN. check your error logs `storage/logs/laravel.log` if that has nothing related check your apache logs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an array of arrays, you will need to access your values by using your predefined offset:

```
@foreach($totals as $total)
    <td>{{ $total['CURRENT']}}</td>
    <td>{{ $total['PRIOR']}}</td>
    <td>{{ $total['FULL']}}</td>
@endforeach
```

Comment: This is incorrect because $totals is multi-dimensional and does not have associative keys itself.

Comment: Yes, that's one way to address it.  I'd argue that $totals does not make sense as a multi-dimensional array though, $totals should be passed to the view as a single-dimensional associative array, but without knowing the OP's controller code or query, it's hard to recommend how to fix that.

Comment: @Devon Exactly. I can only provide a fix for whats known.

Answer (score 0):

When you write queries in Laravel to get (likely) several items using [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent) or the [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries), it will return an instance of the [Collection](https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html) (`Illuminate\Support\Collection`) class containing the results where each result is an instance of the PHP `stdClass` object (in case of using [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries)) or an instance of the Model (when using [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent)). As you can see in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#retrieving-results):

> ### Retrieving Results
>
> The get method returns an `Illuminate\Support\Collection` containing the
>   results where each result is an instance of the PHP `stdClass` object.
>   You may access each column's value by accessing the column as a
>   property of the object:
>
> ```
> foreach ($users as $user) {
>     echo $user->name;
> }
> ```

This is the reason why you can access your element's properties doing: `$object->property`.

I'm guessing that in your query you are modifying the output to suit your needs, so is likely that you modify the result and converted the collection to an associative array. This can also be done when returning result to the view using `compact()`, that also transform the results to an associative array:

```
// something like this
$results = App\MyCoolModel::take(3)->get()->toArray();
// or this
return view('my_cool_view', compact($results));
```

given that now is a simple *array* of *associative arrays* (as your `dd()` shows), you can access the properties the way @adam indicated:

```
@foreach($totals as $total)
    <td>{{ $total['CURRENT']}}</td>
    <td>{{ $total['PRIOR']}}</td>
    <td>{{ $total['FULL']}}</td>
@endforeach
```